# Add event to change input value

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to create a function to change input value in the HTML script. HTML looks like this:

```
<tr>
   <td>6500</td>
   <td>
      <input type="text" size="3" value="3"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>6500</td>
   <td>
      <input type="text" size="3" value="3"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to create an event where the value updates depending on the userinput and change the value so that when I click the button it performs the calculation which Ive already written functions for. I am getting stuck, only thing I have is the cells where userinput is an option. I need to do simle plain js and not jquery.

```
function input() {
var table = document.getElementById("list");
var x = table.getElementsByTagName("input");

console.log(x);
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your html is invalid - your inputs need to be inside a `td`.  Also in your js, where do you define `table`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Pete. i have now updated with more code.

Comment: Are saying you want to update the `value="3"` inside your input with whatever a user types into the same input?

Comment: Yes, whenever a new input is entered.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your code so we get a better idea about your problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I never replied with an answer after your follow up comment, and I know this is terribly late, but if this no longer helps you, it may still help others.

Using JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
    this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
  });
}
```

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('input', 'input', function() {this.setAttribute('value', this.value);});
```